# Set a button as an image in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

I currently have a `UIButton` as a restart button for a game within SpriteKit and I'd like to make it an image. I have declared the button as:

```
var RateBtn: UIButton!
```

Here's current code for button:

```
RestartBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view!.frame.size.width / 3, height: view!.frame.size.height / 3))
RestartBtn.center = CGPointMake(view!.frame.size.width / 2, view!.frame.size.height)
RestartBtn.setTitle("RESTART", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

RestartBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("restart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(RestartBtn)

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: nil, animations: ({
    self.RestartBtn.center.y = self.view!.frame.size.height / 1.4
}), completion: nil)
```

So I have it set out with a spring effect but I now want it as an image instead of font. How do I do this?

Comment: Conventions are that variables and method/function names begin with a lower case letter. Class names begin with an uppercase letter. Also code should be written to be read (we are reading it here) so using full words is more understandable, thus `RestartBtn` is better named `restartButton` and `RateBtn` as `rateButton`. This makes code more understandable to other developers.

Comment: oh okay! yeah sorry I'm new to all of this, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Make the button a SKSpriteNode. 
Detect touch on it by:

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if button.containsPoint(location) {

             //enter restart function here!

        }
    }
```

Comment: In other words, use SKSpriteNodes instead of UIButtons?

Comment: Thank you!

Also for the code I gave, is there a way to change the font and font size?

Comment: Change size of the SKSpriteNode. For example. button.frame.size.width = 100. You could also use a SKLabelNode instead.